# How to find when the thread completed?

Tags: java, multithreading

Do I need to call future.get periodically to check whether the task is executed or not?

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void start(final file avo) throws IOException
{
    Future future = executor.submit(new Callable(){

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        Condee conv = new Condee();
        return conv.doChange(file);
    });

    LOG.debug("Finished the execution serverion");
    executor.shutdown();


}
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more to the point in your question. An ambiguous question like this will likely be closed or deleted.

Answer (score 2):

To check completion you can use [future.isDone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone%28%29), this needs to be constantly checked.

But if you use [future.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29), this method will **wait** until finished and then return the result.

Comment: I have noticed when I use future.get() is blocking the main thread which triggerst the start method and not performing the operation asynchronously. I want to execute the start method asynchronously, what do you suggest?

Comment: The operation is happening asynchronously, but the main thread waits for its completion to get the value when you call get(). If you have something else to do in the main thread (without this return value) you can just do it and call get() after.

Answer (score 1):

Add a call to this before executor.shutdown();

```
future.get();
```

This method will only return when it has completed.

Comment: I commented joaonlima as the operation don't do asynchronously if we do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate? When you call future.get the thread that calls future.get will block but the thread the future is launched on will execute. What is the behavior you are looking for? Who do you want to know when the thread is done in your original question?

Comment: I'm calling the start method from the main thread. When I use future.get, the main thread is also blocked. I want the start method to be operate asynchronously . This created thread shouldn't notify anyone, it has to execute a method when it is done.

Comment: When you call future.get the main thread is the only thread blocked. The execution happens in the executor thread. I see you've edited your question so the answers you've gotten so far no longer apply. What it is you are trying to do? You can either periodically call #isDone or #get with a timeout. But I wouldn't recommend any of those polling approaches as they can be CPU intensive. But its hard to suggest something different when I don't know what your objective is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to retrieve the value sing the get method. You  will either get the result or an exception will be thrown. Here are the four possibilities when you call the get on future:

1. You get the result value
2. You get CancellationException - if the computation was cancelled
   (e.g. Future.cancel(true) is called)
3. You get ExecutionException - if the computation threw an exception
4. You get InterruptedException - if the current thread was interrupted
   while waiting (e.g. executor.shutdownNow() is called)